# How to renew connection of database for iam authentication

Tags: aws-sdk, pg-promise

Using IAM database authentication the password expires after about 15 minutes. So I ideally have to renew the database connection before the password expires. I set up a timer on the first initialization of the database and query the passed time on each query. How can i refresh the password of the connection before the password expires? Or how can i destroy the old database object and renew the object if necessary?

The error message is: "PAM authentication failed for user iam_user".

#### code for getting IAM Password:

```js
const pgp = require('pg-promise')();
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ca =
  '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIID9DCCAtyg...
   ...wZfTUU=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n';

const signer = new AWS.RDS.Signer({
  region: process.env.REGION,
  username: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
  hostname: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
  port: parseInt(`${process.env.DATABASE_PORT}`, 10),
});

module.exports = pgp({
  host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
  port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
  database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
  ssl: { ca },
  dialectOptions: { ssl: { require: true } },
  password: signer.getAuthToken(),
});
```

#### injecting db object to graphql:

```js
const db = require('../db/init');
server.use(
    mount(
      '/graphql',
      graphqlHTTP( () => ({
        schema: schema,
        context: { startTime: Date.now(), db },
        graphiql: true
      })),
    ),
  );
```

#### Using the database in the resolvers.

I could query the time of the creation of the database connection. Is there a possibility to renew the password if necessary? Or what is the best way to destroy the old database object and create a new database object?

```js
const resolvers = {
Query: {
    Post: (root, args, {db}) => {
      console.log(args.id);
      console.log(db.$config.options)
      const postQuery = new PQ({
        text:
          'SELECT post_id as id FROM tbl_post where post_id = $1',
        values: [parseInt(args.id, 10)],
      });
      return db.one(postQuery).catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the relevance of the database connection to your password expiration?

Comment: Hello vitaly-t, first of all i wanted to thank you for your excellent library and you being extremely helpfull to everybody reaching out for help.
As I understood the documentation, i can access (readonly) the connection settings with database.$cn. But i can not renew the password in the database connection. So I tried to to end the pools with pgp.end() / db.$pool.end() and recreating the pool. But then when stresstesting i get connection timeouts. So i was wondering if there is any better way to only change the password in the open database object, which i renew with signer.getAuthToken().

Comment: Why can't use just use a function for password? That's what it does, provides a dynamic password.

Comment: Hello vitaly-t, yes this works:
`password: () => getSignerPassword()`
I observed that the function does not get executed on each invokation of the api. Sometimes is doesnt get executed for up to 10 invokations. Is there any guarantee that the password renewal function gets executed after x time?

Comment: Password-function is only called for new connections. The idea is, when a database password expires, the connection is no longer valid, i.e. broken, in which case the connection fails, then automatically allocated, while getting a new password. Password-function isn't supposed to be called without any reason, since you are working with a connection pool, which caches live connections. Since you are using GraphQL, maybe me that's the crowd you should consult in your case.

Comment: If i connect repeatedly with intervals smaller than 10 seconds, then the password does not get renewed trough the function, but the connection does stay open. If i connect repeatedly with intervals bigger than 10 seconds the password renewal function gets called every invocation. Either way this works. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by vitaly-t i used a password function. To avoid adding latency this functions renews the password only every 15 minutes. If the pool gets continuously used in intervals lower than 10 seconds, than the connection stays open without calling the password function at all. According to my tests there are no new connections to the database opened at all.

```js
const ca = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\9DC...-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n';

const signer = new AWS.RDS.Signer({
    region: process.env.REGION,
    username: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
    hostname: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: parseInt(`${process.env.DATABASE_PORT}`, 10),
});

const SIGNER = { time: 0, password: undefined};

function getSignedPassword() {
    const time = Date.now();
    if (time - SIGNER.time > 900000) {
        SIGNER.time = new Date().getTime();
        SIGNER.password = signer.getAuthToken();
        return SIGNER.password;
    }
  return SIGNER.password;
}

module.exports = pgp({
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
    database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
    user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
    ssl: { ca },
    password: getSignedPassword,
});
```